# Why does Watney’s notebook in The Martian have four holes?

Tags: the-martian, props, worldbuilding

I just watched *The Martian* again and noticed something I missed the first time: Watney's notebook has four holes (instead of three) punched in the left margin, which means it's probably A4 in size (though I didn't get a close enough look to be sure).

This is odd since it's an American mission. Is there an official explanation? If not, what's the likeliest explanation?

1. By 2035 the US has switched to ISO paper formats and metric measurements.
2. Watney stole the notebook from Vogel's personal effects.
3. The production designer thought that that particular notebook looked cool.
4. Other.

Comment: I saw the question title in the sidebar and could not help but think of  [Frog and Toad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frog_and_Toad_Are_Friends#A_Lost_Button) and the lost button, which, you see, also had four holes.

Comment: Well, Nasa has [already decided to use metric since a while](http://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/2007/08jan_metricmoon/). Sure the actual transition takes some time and pockets of imperial units still remain, but you could assume that by 2035 the transition is over.

Comment: @Hoki - And of course, when they don't use metric, things can get expensive and messy; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Climate_Orbiter

Comment: I learned something new today... I didn't even understand the question at first, am I to understand that there is a place in the world where 3 holes are normal?

Comment: @orion yes, that's normal in the US, and probably Canada.

Comment: what do you mean instead of three?

Comment: "By 2035 the US has switched to ISO paper formats and metric measurements" - so, THAT"S why the whole mission ended up screwed up! :)

Comment: Well, I think the metric system works better for math and science, and the customary system works better for cooking and domestic use.

Comment: @XandarTheZenon Sure, but metric can be customary as well.

Comment: @Nils_M Ah, I see what you did there

Comment: ... For variety on the hundreds of cold Martian nights?    (OK, mods delete this and censure me-- I deserve it)

Comment: @orion I learned something new today... I didn't even understand the question at first, am I to understand that there is a place in the world where 4 holes are normal? :P

Comment: @XandarTheZenon The metric system works perfectly fine for cooking and anything else. Honestly, 95% of the world is using metric, if that was really a deal breaker you'd think someone would've noticed over the years.

Comment: @kuhl 95% of the world has two or four hole ring binders actually. Three is pretty much a US idiosyncrasy.

Comment: 4 holes makes more sense many reasons (just like standard paper has mathematical justification). You can fold it in half and you still have two holes. You can punch holes in pairs and you can have a binder with 2 clamps with 2 rings each.  You can use a binder with only middle two rings (they are quite common). 4 holes are also more stable.

Comment: @Voo Just worked it out: it's actually 94.9% of the world population using metric and 95.2% using DIN paper formats. Good guess.

Comment: Question should be "Why don't notebooks of people in the US other than Whatney's character in 'The Martian' have holes for A4 paper like in decent civilized countries".

Answer (score 228, accepted):

I've reached out to the film's [Prop Master](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0184710/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cr91) and the film's [Senior Graphics Artist](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm2107334/) who both kindly responded to my (more than slightly odd) email.

I assume they won't mind my quoting verbatim.

> I don't remember any 4 hole binders. We punched all the hand books to
> 3 holed ones with 2 hooks like NASA does. The binders in bg [background] were
> probably 4 hole just cause it was easier to get. No hidden meaning
> just budget and time. Haha

and

> There are many prop elements that go into a complicated film like the
> Martian and when making decisions about what props should look like we
> firstly research what NASA has used in the past, or what fits into are
> fictional Martian world and helps to tell our story and look good on
> screen.
>
> I'm pleased that you and your friends found the ring binders
> so interesting, I just hope the rest of the film lived up to your
> exacting standards.

Comment: This has to go into the book of SE records as the one answer that goes above and beyond!!!

Comment: Ahhhh would this platform have been that popular when I went to school.... When ever my teacher had asked "What might the author try to tell us" I had answered: "No idea, but lets check SE, some one over there for sure is able to ask the author!" '^.^

Comment: @Zaibis Not really. It used to be *much* easier to get in contact with your favorite author. Famous writers used to be listed in the telephone directory and you could actually just call them. Yes, you could call  Isaac Asimov and ask him if he could tell you the name of this one short story you thought he might have written (it was apparently always The Last Question). Sadly I'm also way too young to have experienced that myself.

Comment: @Voo apparently they all started to go ex-directory when the fans started calling them. By accounts Tolkien was particularly upset because American fans would call him - he got fed up explaining they were calling in the wee hours, UK time.

Comment: @gbjbaanb It was clearly a situation that couldn't scale and I don't even want to consider the practical problems that would cause today. A more innocent time (even if people had apparently problems with the concept of timezones).

Comment: @Rincewind - Glad you approve :-)

Comment: In-universe explanation still needed.

Comment: @djechlin: "No hidden meaning just budget and time." -- Meaning that there is no in-universe explanation possible.

Comment: @DevSolar there's *always* an in-universe explanation, even if the creator doesn't know it :P

Comment: @djechlin: I'll go for "just budget and time" then. NASA wanted to give the astronauts some notebooks, and they couldn't find any cheaper in the nick of time than those A4 ones. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar Well with the US being pretty much the only country not using DIN paper formats, you probably really can get better deals on A4 paper if you order in quantity.

Comment: I'd actually suggest summarising the central answer (as @DevSolar did), especially since the second quote just dodges the question.

Comment: @Lilienthal - There doesn't appear to be a good in-universe reason. It's just a production goof. You might as well ask why the Terminator's face changes so dramatically during the bike chase. http://static.tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pub/images/fcds_e1421792922642t2.png

Comment: @Valorum I know, I'm just pointing out that your answer would be more clear if it actually said that up front. By "central answer" I just meant something like "There was no specific reason, they just used whatever was available."

Comment: @Valorum Nice answer! You went out of your ways to show us that! I was wondering if you could provide us the content of the email you sent? :)

Comment: @keinemaster - "*Noel, I was hoping you could settle a minor bet for me. In The Martian, Mark is consistently shown with a 4-hole binder (European-style) whereas NASA typically use 3-hole binders (US-style). 

Was this prop choice intended to convey a hidden meaning about the nature of society in the year 2035 (something about internationalisation, for example) or was it simply a stylistic choice (e.g. it looked better on screen for some reason)?"*

Answer (score 20):

The Martian was filmed in Hungary and Microsoft lists A4 as the default paper size for that country in its applications adding weight to the suggestion that it was just cheap to go and buy some notepads locally rather than ship them in and they would therefore have likely been A4.

Comment: Paper sizes based on DIN476 are actually the standard everywhere in the world except the US (and Canada). For good reason - it's far superior to the US system. In my experience it's nigh impossible to get letter sized paper outside North America so that's the most likely explanation.

Comment: Agree that DIN format is vastly superior, because of the √2 aspect ratio. In my experience some Latin America countries (e.g. Bolivia) also use a mix of DIN and America paper formats.

Comment: A lot of the movie was shot in Jordan http://www.businessinsider.com/wadi-rum-photos-the-martian-2015-9